# pydoop cp method - how to specify keyword argument "errors"

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am using pydoop to copy files between hdfs locations. The pydoop.hdfs.cp(src_hdfs_path, dest_hdfs_path, **kwargs) method documentation is on this page. https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/api_docs/hdfs_api.html

According to the documentation, the keyword arguments are the same as open() function. So I tried the following code

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
hdfs.cp(srcpath, destpath, errors='ignore')
```

The code works if the file does not exists in the destination path. Otherwise it gives a file already exists error. In other words, the errors='ignore' argument does not work.

Does this look like a pydoop bug or did I supplied the wrong argument?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation says

> errors is an optional string that specifies how encoding and decoding
> errors are to be handled...

`error='ignore'` ignores ***only*** encoding/decoding errors while reading or writing to files.

The error that "file already exists" is thrown by [`hdfs.cp`](https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/blob/3f92f59b237e74cd947993a592ce8eee7aa8ad89/pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py#L199) function.

Comment: Shiva, Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I looked more into the documentation, which shows that this cp method does open the source file therefore encoding is involved. This "errors" argument is only for encoding/decoding errors, as you explained. I was baffled by why pydoop implements a copy method like that. Anyway, I will use other copy methods provided by pydoop package and those methods do not involve openning the source file and also suppress the "file exists" error by simply replacing the existing file.

Comment: The copy method I used is 
pydoop.hdfs.hdfs().copy(from_path, to_hdfs, to_path)